# Tkinter - need a vertical scrollbar in only one window - multiple windows (frames) are within a container

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am writing a tkinter app in Python 3.7, but I haven't worked with GUI before and I am not very experienced. I want to add a canvas with a vertical scrollbar to only one of my three windows. Pages are interconnected via buttons - when I press a button on my StartPage, it takes me to PageOne, and this way I have buttons that take me to the different pages. Each page is a separete class within the main container, and depending on which button I click on (PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree), that page is brought up using show_frame and tkraise. Since all the pages are in one container, I don't know how to implement a scrollbar to just one page within that container. I found an interesting piece of code for the scrollbar here https://gist.github.com/bhaskar-nair2/94b2d4dd511a1cd38ecde9c9481c4b28 but I didn't manage to integrate this into my code. I only need a scrollbar in PageOne window. I would be very grateful for any help.
Here is a part of my code:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()


NORM_FONT = ("Helvetica", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Helvetica", 8)


class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Data Visualisation App")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Menu", font=NORM_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)



        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 3",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.pack()



class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()



class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()




app = MyApp()
app.lift()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(self)  <--- here!!!
        self.frame.pack()  <--- here!!!
```

Where `VerticalScrolledFrame` is from the repo you linked, I just turned all the `orient` and `position` to lowercase and in strings.

Conceptually, there is no difference between how you place the buttons and the scrollbar. If you want to place something in say `PageOne`, you will go into the `__init__` definition of `PageOne` and put `self` in the definition of the frame and pack it.
If you want another point of view, you have a container where you put the pages of your GUI, but those pages are frames, and so can be used as containers themselves for other objects (buttons, labels, scrollbars, other frames etc.).